# Posting Feeds in Facebook Group

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on Facebook SDK. My simple question is. Is Facebook SDK allow us to post feeds in some particular group? If yes, Please provide graphPath for request. I've worked on getting Facebook groups list.

```
- (void) getGroupList 
{

        FBRequest* req = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"/me/?fields=name,groups"];
        FBRequestConnection* reqconn = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];

        [reqconn addRequest:req completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                            id result,
                                            NSError *error){
        FBGraphObject *graphObject = result;
        id<FBGraphUser> graphUser = (id <FBGraphUser>)graphObject;

        NSArray *groupsArray = [[graphUser objectForKey:@"groups"] objectForKey:@"data"];

       for (id groups in groupsArray)
       {
           NSString *groupName = [groups objectForKey:@"name"];
           NSLog(@"Group Name:%@ ", groupName);

       }
       }]; 

       [reqconn start];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/{group-id}/feed"
                             parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(
                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                          id result,
                          NSError *error
                      ) {
                          /* handle the result */
                      }];
```